# Problem with a layout background image

Tags: android, background-image

I am trying to set a image like background image in a layout (by xml or by code)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/my_image">
```

or

```
View myLayout= findViewById( R.id.main_layout);
myLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_image);
```

My problem is than android fix the image in the all background screen, resizing and modifying the image ratio.

How can I set a image, and that the image takes only the neccesary space? (without image resizing)

Comment: if you set android:layout_width="fill_parent" , android:layout_height="fill_parent" also your background "fill_parent"

Answer (score 7):

Without adding an `ImageView` to the layout, if the image is smaller than the space, you can create an [xml bitmap resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap) like the following, and use this in place of the original background image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Comment: The image really is like the full screen (480x800), with a logo in the midle. But when I set the image like background, the image is take up at the visible screen (full screen minus status bar...)

I want avoid to have images for diferents screen resolutions.  :(

Comment: @Jose Maybe you can try fiddling with gravity setting. If you can't get what you want then `ImageView` is the only solution, but remember that w/h ratio changes with devices, and having an image the right size for one might not work everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

Put your LinearLayout inside a RelativeLayout and add an ImageView to that RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

Note that ImageView is the first element in RelativeLayout, causing it to be drawn in background. By declaring fitXY and adjustViewBounds in ImageView, you ensure your image keeps its ratio. You could as well turn adjustViewBounds off and choose another scaleType like fitStart or centerCrop. They also keep aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Jst take another layout inside LinearLayout.

Keet it as Relative so that u can keep that layout wherever You want.
and in that Relative Layout u keep imageView.

And ya that's it i think what u want....

Answer (score 0):

"setBackground" resize the image to fill the View(LinearLayout).
Please add [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) in LinearLayout or RelativeLayout, and then use [setImageResource](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29)  to achieve that.